# Is $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] / \langle x^2+x+1 \rangle $ an integral domain?

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I can prove that it is not a field. But that does not imply that it is not an integral domain either.So I am facing difficulty in solving this. Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: How did you prove it isn't a field?

Comment: If $\Bbb Z_3=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, then $x^2+x+1=(x-1)^2$ over $\Bbb Z_3$.

Comment: WE Tutorial School's comment gives the right solution. But if you can show that $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle X^{2} + X + 1 \rangle$ isn't a field, then it's not a domain either. Indeed, it is a finite ring, and every finite integral domain is a field.

Comment: @MarkBennet Since it is a 2 degree polynomial and has a root in Z3 i.e. 1 so it is reducible and so it is not a maximal ideal and thus not a field.

Comment: But how is it a finite ring? It is a polynomial ring which is never finite.

Comment: You are quotienting out the ring by a polynomial. This, combined with the coefficients being in $\mathbb Z_3$, makes the ring finite (each element is at most a linear polynomial).

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Can you please explain it in detail. It's not clear to me

Comment: It has elements $0$,$1$,$2$, $x$, $x+1$, $x+2$, $-x$, $-x+1$, $-x+2$, so $9$ in all.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma How did you find these elements?

Comment: @Priyanka Since the divisor is a quadratic polynomial, you just list all polynomials of linear degree or les with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_3$.

Comment: It's like $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$: its elements are in correspondence with the *remainders* modulo $n$.

Comment: In the quotient ring we have that $x^2 \equiv -x-1$. So higher powers of $x$ can be replaced by linear or constant terms. The elements I gave are all of them with coefficients modulo 3.

Comment: The point of my question - since I had to go away and not follow the discussion - was to work out whether the proof that it wasn't a field carried immediately to the case of a domain. As others have pointed out, the quotient is finite, and that is well worth understanding. And any finite integral domain is a field (the finiteness can be used with multiplication by non-zero elements and counting to show that multiplicative inverses exist).

Answer (score 1):

$(x-1)^2 = x^2 +x + 1$ over $\Bbb Z_3$, so $y:=[x-1]$ is nonzero in the quotient with $y^2= 0$. So it's not an integral domain.

In general, note that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial over a field $F$, and it's *not* irreducible, so $p(x)=q(x)r(x)$, for non trivial polynomials then the quotient $F[x]{/}\langle p(x) \rangle$ has $[q(x)]$ and $r(x)]$ as zero-divisors. So $F[x]{/}\langle p(x) \rangle$ has two options: a field (if $p(x)$ is irreducible), or "plain" commutative unitary ring if $p(x)$ is not.